# How does function addN give answer 12 and 102

Tags: function, return, invoke

How does function work? How does x get a number?

```
function addN(n) {
 var adder = function(x) {
        return n + x;
    };
 return adder;
}

var add2 = addN(2);
console.log(add2(10));
console.log(add2(100));
```

Comment: what did you expect it to do?

Comment: I mean how does it get the result of 102 and 12 in the first place?